# Close browser window with specific url (opened by different browser)

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory

I am doing an application where when the user click on social login it opens a new window. Let's say my application is running on Chrome and my default browser was set to Edge; the URL is getting opened in Edge. After successful token generation it is redirecting to the application without closing the browser window/tab.

I am using azure AD authentication as follows

```cs
IPublicClientApplication app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
  .Create(azMapping.ClientId)
  .WithAuthority(authority)                                            
  .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost:44342/Default.aspx")
  .Build();

result = app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
  .WithSystemWebViewOptions(new SystemWebViewOptions())
  .ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken.None)
  .GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

The authority URL opens in the default browser. Is there a way to open the URL on the application running or can we close once we got back the response?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [destinationpageurl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.destinationpageurl?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#definition) property

The [DestinationPageUrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.destinationpageurl?view=netframework-4.8) property specifies the page that is displayed when a login attempt is successful.

Or

You can use the JavaScript to achieve this `window.location.href` returns the href (URL) of the current page

`Response.Redirect` should work if you just want to navigate to the same window page.

refer [here for Open url in same window](https://www.codeproject.com/Answers/1252207/Open-url-in-same-window)

You can have a look to how to handle it [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23224434/open-new-window-for-social-login-and-then-close-and-return-to-parent-on-success)